# How to define mongoose schema inside shcema

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

Here is an example:

```
    var aaaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
    });

    var testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        test: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
    });
```

For now, test could be any Object since it is: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
I want to define test is:

```
   {
       aa: aaaSchema,
       bb: aaaSchema,
       ....
    }
```

It means that the key could be any string (aa, bb, or others), the value must be {name: String} which is aaaSchema.

Comment: If the intended Model for `test` needs to allow for any property then can it  have a defined schema? 

Comment: I want the test could have any key, but the value must follow some patten which is the aaaScheme.   Is that impossible?

Answer (score 0):

[Subdocuments](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) can be used for embedded documents.

```
var aaaSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });
var testSchema = new Schema({ test: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed });

var mainSchema = new Schema({
  aa: aaaSchema,
  bb: aaaSchema
});
```

Comment: Is there any typo? I did not get your answer.  Where the mainSchema come from? I need the testSchema follow some patten.